# How could I transfer message from my File Inbound adapter to Sftp Outbound adapter through Spring DSL in java 1.7

Tags: spring-integration

How could I transfer message from my File Inbound adapter to Sftp Outbound adapter through Spring DSL in java 1.7 as I have two separtae flow for File  Inbound adapter and Sftp Outbound adapter, but I could not able to send the mesage from Sftp Outbound adapter though my InBound adapter is working fine.
I want to do some thing like this... But I am struggling to convert this thing to my integration flows.

Message message = this.fileReadingResultChannel.receive();
                 this.toSftpChannel.send(message);

Can some one please help me out as I stuck over here and not able to proceed.

My File Inbound flow look like this..

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {          
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(fileMessageSource(),
                    new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>() {

                        @Override
                        public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec e) {
                            e.autoStartup(true).poller(Pollers.fixedRate(6000)
                                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(1));
                        }
                    }).transform(Transformers.fileToByteArray())
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("fileReadingResultChannel"))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageSource<File> fileMessageSource() {

    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File(localDir));    
    source.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);        
    return source;
}
```

This is my sftp outbound flow..

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpOutboundFlow() {
    System.out.println("enter out  bound flow.....");
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("toSftpChannel")
            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)
                    .remoteFileSeparator("\\")
                    .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                    .remoteDirectory(remDir)).get();
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560429/spring-integration-dsl-running-sftp-outbound-flow-from-main-class).
Just wire the two flows together with the same channel.
What is it that you still don't understand?

Comment: Hi Gary, Sorry for my silly question but really I am not able to wire the two flows together correctly. As last time you told that I need to add a "PublishSubscribeChannel"  in my flow, and this point I am not able to proceed and really struggling. Also I have shared my new flow in my other question. So could you please mention in that flow how to use this.

Comment: The pub/sub channel was needed because you wanted to do something after the sftp transfer - this time you don't mention that at all. If you just want to detect a file and transfer it, just wire the above flows together. Please explain in much more detail what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Hi Gary, Yes I need to look up all files from local directory and transfer those files to remote directory through Sftp OutBound adapter. 
 This is the reason I have written two flows one is file inbound which is detect the files from local directory and other one is Sftp Outbound flow which will transfer those file to the remote directory. The above posted two flows was working fine but I am not able to wire the two flows together correctly. After the Sftp outbound transfer successfully I dont  need anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to read the file into memory; the sftp adapter will read it and send it directly.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow transferFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("/tmp/foo")),
                new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>() {

                    @Override
                    public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec e) {
                        e
                        .autoStartup(true)
                        .poller(Pollers
                            .fixedDelay(5000)
                            .maxMessagesPerPoll(1));
                    }
                })
            .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                    .remoteDirectory("destDir"))
            .get();
}
```

If you want to keep it as 2 separate flows, simply join them with a channel bean:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel foo() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

end the first one with `.channel(foo())` and start the second one with `.from(foo())`.

Comment: HI Gary, Thanks a lot for your answer............ it solved my problem also now I am able to understand how to wire the two flows together.